# Attach an HTML block "more times" by avoiding code repetitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Supposing that I've a block `myBox` defined as follows:

```
<div class="myBoxClass" id="myBox">
    <h1>My Box</h1>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="My Picture" /></a>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Then, I've defined two containers, `containerA` and `containerB`:

```
<div id="containerA">
    <!-- Attach MyBox -->
</div>
<div id="containerB">
    <!-- Attach MyBox -->
</div>
```

I'd like to attach `MyBox` inside the two containers, by avoiding code repetitions.

Which is the best way to do that?

---

**Note**: I'm looking for a client-side solution, useful to define some *responsive* sections.

Comment: You can do that.. but id should be unique..!

Comment: already id be unique which is id is repeated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that by,

```
$("#containerA,#containerB").html($('.myBoxClass').clone());
```

But be aware that id is going to be repeated. That makes the html **invalid**.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SxGS6/)

And you can avoid the redundancy by giving them unique id after placing them into the DOM,

```
$("#containerA,#containerB")
     .html($('.myBoxClass').clone())
          .find('.myBoxClass').attr('id', function (i,val) {
                 return val + (i+1);
            });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SxGS6/1/)

If the give html structure of `myBoxClass` differs from, what you shown up here, by means of additional elements with id then you should write the code as per *T.J* said,

```
 $("#containerA,#containerB")
         .html($('.myBoxClass').clone())
              .find('[id]').attr('id', function (i,val) {
                     return val + (i+1);
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

The server-side option is to wrap `myBox` in a PHP function (or some other server-side language) that echoes/returns the HTML and call said function in the place of your comments.  The client-side option is to do the same with Javascript/jQuery.  Both are relatively trivial implementations so I won't bother with examples unless you need one (but it's hard to recommend which to use without more info about your site/setup).

However, make sure you iterate the IDs as they must be unique (e.g. `#myBox1` and `#myBox2`)

Comment: No, you should bother the OP with examples. Really.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Fair enough. If he mentions needing a native JS or PHP implementation I'll edit - there are plenty of jQuery examples in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$("[id^=container]").append($(".myBoxClass").clone());
```

Or

```
$("[id^=container]").html($(".myBoxClass").clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
$("[id^=container]").append($(".myBoxClass").clone());
```

The above code will select all the id's starts with `container`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/224/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.outerHtml` in jquery

```
$("[id^=container]").append($('#myBox')[0].outerHTML);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SxGS6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this my adding the code to a separate page and using .load() JQuery function to load it where you want.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Projects:</b>
<ol id="new-projects"></ol>

<script>
$( "#something-new" ).load( "/resources/myBox.html #box li" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

clone your html tag.

```
 $("#containerA,#containerB").html($('.myBoxClass').clone());
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var myBox=$(
                 '<div class="myBoxClass" id="myBox">'
                +'<h1>My Box</h1>'
                +'<a href="#"><img src="myPic.png" alt="My Picture" /></a>'
                +'<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>'
                +'</div>'
           );
```

Now You got a Jquery Object.

Use this where ever you want.

```
$('#containerA').append(myBox);
 $('#containerB').append(myBox);
```